# PHP Converting UTF-8 to TeX/LaTeX Formatting?

Tags: php, encoding, latex, tex

I have some strings that include encoding that would work with TeX, (For example they look like "Pi/~na Colada" instead of Piña Colada). Is there a simple way to convert this to show properly without creating my own function to convert the characters?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

But:

1. The tex.stackexchange.com wiki has a [decent list of TeX accents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/accents/info).
2. Then you just need to correlate them with their [UTF-8 combining mark](https://cloford.com/resources/charcodes/utf-8_diacritical-marks.htm).
3. Make sure you move the combining mark to *after* the character you want it combined with.

   - eg: `"/~n"` to `"n" . $combining_mark`
4. You might then want to run it through intl's [Normalizer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php) in NFC form to compose the character into a single codepoint, if it exists.